# Какие возможные проблемы для безопасности есть в данном примере авторизации на php?

Tags: php, cookie, авторизация

На собеседовании получил задание сделать код ревью.
Мои замечания были:

1. Пароль в БД храниться в открытом виде без хеширования
2. При передаче user_id не приводим к числу (там может быть что угодно, включая иньекцию)
3. Пароль пользователя храниться в куках - вместо этого я бы хранил id сессии

```
<?php

$userProfile = unserialize($_COOKIE['user_profile']);
$user = new User();
$user->importById($userProfile['user_id']);

if ($userProfile['password_hash'] != md5($user->getPassword())) {
   throw new Exception('Permission denied');
}

(new UserProfileController((int)$userProfile['user_id']))->run();
```

Comment: минимум md5 не используется для паролей уже лет 10. Потому что его подобрать легко. Что скрыто в методах importById и конструкторе UserProfileController и методе run - неизветсно. возможно там дырища ещё больше чем использование md5

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.